# Cannot reload AVD list: For input string: "" Could not load wear device Error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

See my error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTmqa.png).

> Cannot reload AVD list: For input string: "" Could not load wear
>   device Error  in android studio

How  to fix  it?

Comment: I am also having this issue. It occurs when I try to run an app in Android Studio 1.5.1. The error dialog pops up repeatedly, blocking the Device Chooser window. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Delete all virtual devices from 
AVD MANAGER

**any device created**

[image: Nothing devices]

and install Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image[image: my sdk manager]

my solutions this trouble

Version Android Studio 1.5.1